# CSV with nested structs

Tags: csv, rust, serde

I'm trying to serialize an object made of nested structs to CSV. The reason for nesting is purely code organization and I don't expect it to remain after serialization. This code example represents what I have [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6dfe1dbbb49b329e8ede109ea60b247d)

```rust
use serde::Serialize;
use std::io;

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct UserInfo {
    id: String,
    username: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct User {
    user_info: UserInfo,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut wtr = csv::Writer::from_writer(io::stdout());
    wtr.serialize(User {
        user_info: UserInfo {
            id: "1".to_string(),
            username: "Jon".to_string(),
        },
    })?;
    wtr.flush()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Running this gives me this error

> Error(Serialize("cannot serialize UserInfo container inside struct when writing headers from structs"))

I tried adding `#[serde(flatten)]` to `user_info`, but that's also not supported according to this [issue](https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-csv/issues/239).

What would be a workaround for this? I don't mind adding the headers manually if that would help. I just want to keep the nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround in the comment thread under the issue you linked:

> ```
> use serde::Serialize;
> fn main() {
>   let mut w = csv::Writer::from_writer(std::io::stdout());
>   w.serialize(Data::<CustomColumns>::default()).unwrap();
> }
>
> #[derive(Debug, Serialize, Default)]
> struct Data<Extra: Serialize + Default>(DataInner, Extra);
>
> #[derive(Debug, Serialize, Default)]
> struct DataInner {
>   a: usize,
>   b: String,
> }
>
> #[derive(Debug, Serialize, Default)]
> struct CustomColumns {
>   custom: String,
> }
> ```

That is, make the top most struct a tuple struct, and put all previously nested structs thereby removing the unsupported nesting side by side in it for example:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct UserInfo {
    id: String,
    username: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct UserRow(User, UserInfo);

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct User {
    other_user_field: &'static str,
}
```